# Multichoicefield with checkbox in django with Model forms

Tags: django, forms, model

I am initializing a model form in django and later adding a multichoicefield with choices displayed as inline checkboxes that are being used to update an Arrayfield on my model.

Model Code:

```
Class Data(models.Model): 
    my_array = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True), null=True)
```

Form Code to initialize a Multichoice field corresponding to choices for my_array:-

```
class DataForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Data
        fields = ('my_array')
    my_choice = (('','None'), ('A','A'), ('B','B'), ('C','C'))
    my_array = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=my_choice , widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=False)
```

Checked values are saving correctly into the ArrayField 'my_array'. I am having problems retrieving these values on this form.

I need this multichoicefield to have checked (selected) values based on saved model when it is retrieved for a previously filled out form. Currently when the model is retrieved I am getting values corresponding to my_array but checkboxes are not checked. It seems like my definition of my_array on forms is not using my_array field from Model to prefill these checkboxes. Any idea on how this could be done?

Comment: Are you saving the values in your views after the actions are completed? That's where your problem will be.

Comment: Yes values are getting saved in a post to the view and when I query my model I am getting back these values as an array

Comment: Actually you were somewhat right about values not being saved properly. On close examination I found that instead of the choices being saved as ['A','B','C'] in my model some were saved as [['A,B,C']] in a single object. It turns out that this was due to a problem in converting Charfield to Arrayfield on PostGres db on previously saved data. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

On careful observation I noticed that some values on my model were saved as [['A','B','C']] instead of ['A','B','C'] which was why while instantiating a form from a model for these it was not able to select these values.

This happened because at some point I converted my_array on my model from Charfield to ArrayField and correspondingly also ran a script on Postgresql to convert existing values.

I am still not sure why but some of these converted values are coming out to be comma delimited in a single array object instead of being split into multiple array objects. I hope this will help avoid running into this problem again and if I find a fix for doing these conversions the right way I will post it here.